# A disjoint union is not connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Consider the set $\coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ with the disjoint union
>   topology. Prove that this space is not connected, even if all the
>   components are connected.

**Attempt**: Consider the disjoint union $(\mathbb{R} \times \{1\}) \cup (\mathbb{R} \times \{2\})$

Then, $\mathbb{R} \times \{1\}$ is open, and also closed because $$\mathbb{R} \times \{1\} = (\mathbb{R} \times \{1\}) \cup (\mathbb{R} \times \{2\}) \setminus(\mathbb{R} \times \{2\})$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but this doesn't count as a proof. What you have proved is that the following statement is *false*:

> A disjoint union of (connected) spaces, $\coprod_{i \in I} X_i$, is always connected.

However, what you have been asked to prove is that the following statement is *true*:

> A disjoint union of (connected) spaces, $\coprod_{i \in I} X_i$, is always disconnected.

(Pedantic remark: it actually *isn't* true as it stands. But if you exclude the cases when $|I| = 0$ or $|I| = 1$, then it becomes true. I presume this was the intention of the author of the question.)

Comment: Thanks. There was no author, just a question I asked myself, and was stated in the way you phrased, but I have to admit that I was a little careless while formulating.

Answer (score 0):

If we have at least $|I| \ge 2$ and all $X_i \neq \emptyset$ (or at least two of them are non-empty) then $X \times \{i\}$ is open and closed and non-empty (as $X_i$ is) and not the whole space (if $j \neq i$, then $X_j \times \{j\}$ is a non-empty set in its complement).
A disjoint union of at least $2$ non-empty open sets is never connected.